# unable to add Firewall Rule to Azure Key Vault using PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I want to add / remove firewall rules to Azure Key Vault. I am using the below cmdlets to achieve it. The cmdlets just run and do not output anything. And from the portal - firewall section of Key Vault, no rule gets updated.

I have tried all possible combinations. Like, adding/removing "/32", adding/removing "resource group", using "keyVault" object, etc., nothing seems to be working.

Are the cmdlets broken or am I missing anything? Please help me.

```
Remove-AzureRmKeyVaultNetworkRule -VaultName "testfwrulekeyvault" -IpAddressRange "3.3.3.3/32"

Add-AzureRmKeyVaultNetworkRule -VaultName "testfwrulekeyvault" -IpAddressRange "2.2.2.2"
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to enable the service endpoints of your Vnet and subnet. And at the end, you should update the key vault and set the default action to `Deny` to turn on the network rules. See all the steps about [Configure Azure Key Vault firewalls and virtual networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-network-security).

**Update**

If you just want to add the rules through the Powershell command `Add-AzureRmKeyVaultNetworkRule` or `Remove-AzureRmKeyVaultNetworkRule`. Then it works when you execute them without error. See the screenshot:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The link tells us to configure "endpoints" when adding virtual network/subnets. But I am trying to add a "firewall" rule, not VNET or subnet. However, I have used the "AZ" module as well as shown in the link. But still the firewall does not get updated.

Comment: @ManjunathRao Well, do you use the command `(Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName "mykeyvault").NetworkAcls` to list the rules?

Comment: @ManjunathRao Just refresh the web page.

Comment: I logged off and logged in again and worked. But, refreshing the page is a better option. Thanks!!